# Determining if a subset is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have the following: $span{(1, 1, 0, 1)} \cup span{(1, 0, 1, 1)}$

How can I determine if this subset of $R^4$ is a subspace of $R^4$?

Comment: If it is a subspace, we should expect it is closed under sums, esp.  the sum of the two generators should be in the unions - but is it?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, you are right! We would have to check if its closed under sums. However, I'm not sure how to do that in this case. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

We have this general result:

$$A\cup B\;\text{is a subspace}\Rightarrow (A\subset B)\lor(B\subset A)$$

In fact if $(A\not\subset B)\land(B\not\subset A)$ so let $a\in A\setminus B$ and $b\in B\setminus A$ and let $z=a+b$ then $z\in A\cup B$ so WLOG assume $z\in A$ hence $z-a=b\in A$. Contradiction. Can you apply this result for your question?

Comment: The notation is very confusing.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand the logic notation?

Comment: I think the notation is just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Use the subspace test to determine whether or not it is a subspace.

(1) It must contain the zero vector
(2) It must be closed under vector addition
(3) It must be closed under scalar multiplication

If it meets those three conditions, then it is a subspace.

Comment: I know these three rules, but I'm not sure how to implement these with this questions? :(

Comment: Could you please use these three rules to show me how to solve the problem because Ive been on this problem for a while and don't understand this. Thank you.

Comment: (2) For $u, w \in \mathbb{W}, u+w \in \mathbb{W}$ (3) For $u \in \mathbb{W}, r \in \mathbb{R}, ru \in \mathbb{W}$, where $\mathbb{W} is your subspace$

Comment: so for (2) it would be [1 1 0 1] + [1 0 1 1] = [2 1 1 2], but how do we know that this is closed under addition?

Comment: So I can choose [4 0 4 4] and [5 5 0 5] and adding them would give me [9 5 4 9]/ How would this show closure under addition?

Comment: you need to use arbitrary vectors $u$ and $w$. Think of a general form to all vectors in the span

Comment: Here is a big hint: The vectors in the span are all of the form [a+b a b a+b]

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: By definition, any vector in $\mathrm{span}{(1, 1, 0, 1)} \cup \mathrm{span}{(1, 0, 1, 1)}$ either has a zero 3-nd component, or a zero 2-rd component (or both).

What if we take a non-zero vector $\mathbf{u} \in \mathrm{span}{(1, 1, 0, 1)}$ and a non-zero vector $\mathbf{v} \in \mathrm{span}{(1, 0, 1, 1)}$ and add them?